# Upgrade project frm OS7.0 to OS7.1, GetFilenames Not working for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Before change the Project from OS 7.0 to OS 7.1 , the below code is working. After upgrading, the code is not workig. Would appreciate help how to make this isolatedStorage works.

using (var store1 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {

if (store1.DirectoryExists("Contacts"))
   {
               strFileName = "Contacts\";

string[] fileList = store1.GetFileNames(strFileName);


              if (fileList.Length <= 0)
               {

                      txtBlkMsg.Text = "No Contact file created. ";
                      listBox1.ItemsSource = null;
                }
                else
               {

                      listBox1.ItemsSource = fileList;
                }
            }
            else
             {

                 txtBlkMsg.Text = "You have not created any contact file ";
             }

}
}

Comment: What isn't working? GetFileNames throws an error or just doesn't return anything? Are you sure you have files in the Contacts folder?

Comment: I have added data or files. I really cannot find the bug. I tested the app in two version:OS7.0 and 7.1, only the App with OS7,0 is working. There is no error and tested  The strFilename= "Contacts\\" or strFilename =@"Contacts\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OS7.1 required a search pattern.

A search pattern. Both single-character ("?") and multi-character ("*") wildcards are supported.

Adding a * solved my problem.